# ModelSim 10.5 All Optimizations are Disabled Error

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I am running `ModelSim SE-64 10.5` on `windows 10`  and when I wanna simulate `any` module I run into the following error:

```
vsim -gui work.registerFileTB -novopt
# vsim -gui work.registerFileTB -novopt
# Start time: 15:20:14 on Dec 23,2020
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-12110) All optimizations are disabled because the -novopt option is in effect. This will cause your simulation to run very slowly. If you are using this switch to preserve visibility for Debug or PLI features, please see the User's Manual section on Preserving Object Visibility with vopt. -novopt option is now deprecated and will be removed in future releases.
# Error loading design
# End time: 15:20:14 on Dec 23,2020, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
# Errors: 1, Warnings: 0
```

Comment: vsim --help should show you all available commands. Like I remember there is command which degrades the error to warning.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self explanatory—remove the `-novopt` switch. Check the user manual for what you should use instead

Answer (score -1):

After starting the simulation with optimization, I could not see the objects. Without optimization there is the same error.

1. Set enable optimization.
2. Open "Optimization options..."
3. In the tab Visibility: set "Apply full visibility to all modules"